# Fundamental group of simple graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Find the fundamental groups of graphs A, B and C as shown:

[image: graphs]

They look simple but I am unsure what their fundamental groups would be.

I was thinking that $A$ and $B$ are generated by just one element so $\pi(A)=\pi(B)=\mathbb{Z}$. Is this correct?

It would be good to get some insight into the ideas ebhind this problem so I can understand what is going on

Comment: I think you get more insight by considering the fundamental groupoid on a set of base points, which in this case would be the set of vertices. Then you see the use of the notion of **free groupoid**. See the book advertised on http://www.groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html ,

Answer (score 2):

$\pi_1(A)$ and $\pi_1(B)$ are trivial since they are contractible, $\pi_1(C)$ is the free group generated by 2 elements since $C$ retract to the bouquet of two loops.

Comment: ok thanks! So in a more general case, if $G$ is the graph retractable to $n$ loops,its trivial group will be the free group of $n$ generators?